# Authentication JSON parse error with ReactJS using Alfresco 5.1.e CE Login REST API

Tags: json, rest, reactjs, alfresco

I'm trying to login with my ReactJS app using the login REST API of Alfresco CE 5.1.e, but I have the next error in the console of my browser:

> syntax error json parse unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the json data

This error don't happen with Alfresco CE 4.2.e, and I have an application with React Native and the login it's works with 4.2.e and 5.1.e. **I have configured CORS in Alfresco.** I suppose which the problem is in ReactJS, I'm use the next code:

**api-client.js**

```
function loginAlfresco(user, pass)
{
    return fetch(alfrescoLocal + "api/login",
    {
        method: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        body: JSON.stringify(
        {
            username: user,
            password: pass
        })
    })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then(data => alert(data))
    .catch(error => alert("Error" + error))
};
```

**Login.js**

```
loginAlfresco() {
     loginAlfresco(this.state.username, this.state.password)
        .then((data) =>
          this.setState({ticket: data})
        ).catch((error) =>
          alert(error)
        )
};
```

The JSON sent is:

```
{
   "username":"user",
   "password":"12345"
}
```

The response in the console of Chrome is:

> Solicitud desde otro origen bloqueada: la política de mismo origen
> impide leer el recurso remoto en
> http://EXTERNAL-IP:8082/alfresco/s/api/login (razón: falta la cabecera
> CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin').

And the network Chrome:

> ```
> Request URL: http://EXTERNAL-IP:8082/alfresco/s/api/login
> Request Method: POST
> Status Code: 200 OK
> Remote Address: localhost:8082
> ```

Any idea?

Comment: Post a copy of the data you are trying to parse.

Comment: Thanks, I added it...

Comment: Can you use the browser developer tools to see exactly what is being sent and received?

Comment: Ok, I added it...

Comment: Are you trying to access Alfresco from the same host that it's deployed to, or a different one?

Comment: Alfresco is located in an external server, I put "localhost" as an example. Probably not understood, I changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the Alfresco CORS configuration, I change the "cors-filter-1.9.3.jar" library located in the "tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/lib" folder to a newer version "cors-filter-2.4.jar ", and it was solved.